# How to enforce a rewrite or redirect for an nginx reverse proxyed location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use Nginx to reverse proxy a node.js app on a sub-directory of my main website which is also reversed proxied.

The / reverse proxy works as expected however the second location does not load any assets...

I am using the below config:

```
    location / {

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.104:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                       
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
    }

    location /new/ {

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                       
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  

    }
```

This works in as much as when I go to the ./new url I can see the default page of the node.js app but no images, css or js assets are loaded.

When I check the browser console I can see loading errors that show that the browser is trying to load the assets from the / location...

Also the links shown on the page loaded at ./new also point to the / location so they also do not work...

I have been trying to work out how to resolve this and have seen that rewrite or return commands in the `nginx.conf` file can be used to redirect the browser but none of these seem to work to correct my issue... or I may be misunderstanding how to use them as I see a 'too many redirects' error page when trying to load from the ./new URL...

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your app to prepend its root path to urls, nginx does not alter proxied content.

Comment: Thank you, I have found that the node app I am trying to proxy to the /new/ location uses webpack and babel internally - and I will need to change the use of babel to the 'file-loader' module to deal with the routing/serving of assets from within the app... I am marking your answer as correct as you are right to tell me to check the app rather than the nginx.conf config... this would have saved me a hell of a lot of head scratching as I was 'sure' it was a nginx issue - but in the mean time I also found out about the webpack issue...